# Quantify docstrings in python project

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

Is there anyway to quantify the percentage of docstrings in a python project, concerning all modules, function, classes, methods, etc.?

I didn't found any package or linter offering that.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this amazing package: https://github.com/HunterMcGushion/docstr_coverage#readme